# Creating and Updating User Table With PHP/MySql Script

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading a book on PHP, MYSQL, JAVASCRIPT and JQUERY.  While reading, I do type the code and see how it worked.  I have the following script which I ran to create a table named: "users', and subsequently update the table with two users.  When I ran the script in my browser, it only created the new table but failed to update it with the new users.  I do not receive any error.  Below is the entire script.

```
<?php // setup_users.php 

require_once 'login.php';

$connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query = "CREATE TABLE users (

    forename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    surname  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
    )";

$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) die($connection->error);

$salt1 = "qm&g";
$salt2 = "ph!@";

$forename = 'Baban';
$surname = 'Sadik';
$username = 'bsadik';
$password = 'babansadik1';
$token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$password$salt2");

add_user($connection, $forename, $surname, $username, $token);

$forename = 'Abdullah';
$surname = 'Abubakar';
$username = 'aabubakar';
$password = 'abakar1';
$token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$password$salt2");

add_user($connection, $forename, $surname, $username, $token);

function add_user($connection, $fn, $sn, $un, $pw) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$forename', '$surname', '$username', '$token')";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);

}

?>
```

Where did go wrong please?

Comment: _“Where did go wrong please?”_ – in not enabling proper PHP error reporting. PHP would have told you that these variables do not exist in the function scope - if only you’d _let_ it. So please go do that first thing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed to put column names in the insertion query in add_user function and you are passing undefined variables
Do like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(forename, surname, username, password)
        VALUES('$fn', '$sn', '$un', '$pw')";
```

Comment: I inserted the same code but the table still did not update.  I keep getting the message: "Table 'users' already exists" whenever I ran the script again.  The table is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_user` function has parameters different to what you are trying to use in the query itself.

Change the query to the following:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES('$fn', '$sn', '$un', '$pw')
```

Note that you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead, as currently the code is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. If the book you're using doesn't contain information on using prepared statements, scrap the book and find one that does instead.

Comment: I changed it as advised, bu the table did not update, still.

Comment: @shallowGeek as per your comment on another answer, make sure you delete the `users` table before running the script again

Comment: @shallowGeek no problem, if the answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick mark :)

Comment: @shallowGeek any reason why you accepted my answer and then changed it to the other answer?